# Translate splunk index data to JSON using cli search

Tags: json, search, command-line-interface, splunk

I have a splunk container running on docker, and was hoping to translate the raw splunk index data into json using a cli search and saving the output as a local file. How to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI command is (surprise!) `search`.

```
splunk search "your SPL query" -maxout 0 -output json -wrap  0 > local_file
```

The `-maxout 0` option allows an unlimited number of events in the output, however, the output size is still limited to 50k.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.1/SearchReference/CLIsearchsyntax for all of the available options.