# Splunk cli search to get all events

Tags: command-line-interface, splunk, splunk-query

I have a splunk container running on docker and I have some raw splunk index data (zeek, goose, iris_plus, etc.) with `db` directories containing `.tsidx`, `.data`, `.dat` files, and a `journal` file. How (and where) can I run a CLI search to get all possible events?

TIA!

Comment: You already accepted an answer to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733372/translate-splunk-index-data-to-json-using-cli-search

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translate splunk index data to JSON using cli search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733372/translate-splunk-index-data-to-json-using-cli-search)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, in this question I am looking for 1) a query to get all possible events from each index, and 2) where to be running my cli search to get that output. should i run the search in the the rawdata directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for very small Splunk installations, a single CLI command is unlikely to be able to retrieve all indexed data before reaching the 50k output size limit.  You'll have to run multiple commands to get it all.

Where you run the search doesn't matter because Splunk knows where to find the data on your behalf.

The query itself is simple: `index=foo earliest=0 latest=now`.  Be sure to replace `foo` with the name of the index you want to search.

Comment: Thanks. I tried running `/opt/splunk/bin/splunk search index=bro earliest=0 latest=now -maxout 0 -output json -wrap  0 > ~/t.json`

but got `{"preview":false,"messages":[{"type":"WARN","text":"The following arguments were unknown or had no effect: 'count'"}],"lastrow":true}`

Comment: The search string should be in quotes.  `/opt/splunk/bin/splunk search "index=bro earliest=0 latest=now" -maxout 0 -output json -wrap  0 > ~/t.json`.  FTR, I just ran a similar query that produced 167MB output so the 50k limit may not always apply.